# Using database with Google Maps API Store Locator

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My question is pretty much highlighted here:

[Using database with Store Locator on Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923599/using-database-with-store-locator-on-google-maps-api)

Although I'm trying to create something using only javascript, html & css, but the only answer on this question is in php. Is there a way to do it without?

Comment: So you want a database, but no server-side language? How do you hold your data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. First you need to have a set of data like

```
[
   {name:"shop 1",lat:149.23532000,long:-35.35248400},
   {name:"shop 2",lat:148.23532000,long:-34.35248400},
   {name:"shop 3",lat:147.23532000,long:-33.35248400}
]
```

Then use the [formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate the distance for each of the shop
using lat and long, output those distance
within the distance you specify say like 5 km.
You can also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) and [here](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml)

Comment: although I need to pull that from a database?

Comment: to do it easily without reading all those math calc you can just plugin the mysql calculation into your mysql and output the results in json for your frontend to consume.